# how to set javascript variable to php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I want to set $lat and $lon from google map. I mean, I want to set those variables when user drags the marker to the specific location and then set them to my form without AJAX and finally send it to the server.
To say more clearly, I want to get all values like title, description , latitude and longitude ... in this page.
Here is my code. I bring it briefly .

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="yes">
    <input id="searchAdd" type="text" class="form-control" onfocus="initialFill()" placeholder="Enter Address">
    <div id="location_incident"  style="height:400px;">
        <script>
            showCurrent(locationOfIncident);
        </script>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="title">
</form>
<script>
 var latIncident, lonIncident,map, marker;
  function locationOfIncident(current){
    var lat=current.coords.latitude;
    latIncident=lat;
    var lon=current.coords.longitude;
    lonIncident=lon;
    var mapOption={
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        zoom:8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_incident'),mapOption);
    marker= new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
            map:map,
            draggable:true,
            title:'Location of Incident'
        });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(res){
                                                    latIncident=res.latLng.lat();
                                                    lonIncident=res.latLng.lng();
                                                    getAddress(latIncident,lonIncident);
   });
}
function showCurrent(s){

if(navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(s);
}

}
var add={};

function getAddress(lat,lon){

var LatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'latLng':LatLng}, function(results,status){
    if(status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
        if(results[0]){
                add['address']=(results[0].formatted_address);
        }
    }
});

}
</script>
```

Comment: You have to use hidden fields for lat,long etc. Set them in locationOfIncident() function , Get them on server side after submit.

Answer (score 0):

Set hidden fields in form for lat, long etc(whatever you want).

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long">
    <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="yes">
    <input id="searchAdd" type="text" class="form-control" onfocus="initialFill()" placeholder="Enter Address">
    <div id="location_incident"  style="height:400px;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        showCurrent(locationOfIncident);
    </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var latIncident, lonIncident,map, marker;
function locationOfIncident(current)
{
    var lat=current.coords.latitude;
    latIncident=lat;
    var lon=current.coords.longitude;
    lonIncident=lon;
    var mapOption={
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        zoom:8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_incident'),mapOption);
    marker= new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        title:'Location of Incident'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(res){
        latIncident=res.latLng.lat();
        lonIncident=res.latLng.lng();
        getAddress(latIncident,lonIncident);
    });
}
function showCurrent(s)
{
    if(navigator.geolocation){
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(s);
    }
}
var add={};

function getAddress(lat,lon)
{

    $('#long').val(lon);
    $('#lat').val(lat);

    var LatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng':LatLng}, function(results,status){
        if(status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            if(results[0]){
                add['address']=(results[0].formatted_address);
            }
        }
    });

}
</script>
```